# How access document class's normal paragraph indent size?

Tags: indentation, theorems, amsthm

I want to modify the standard `amsthm` environment `proof` so that its beginning, *including* the word "Proof", is indented by the same amount as any normal text paragraph.

How do I refer to the size of a normal text paragraph's indentation so that I can use it as a length with `\hskip`, as in:

```
\makeatlatter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\SOMETHING       %% WHAT GOES IN PLACE OF "SOMETHING"
      \itshape
    #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
} 
\makeatother
```

I'd like this to be independent of any particular documentclass or the class's base font-size option, which is why I want to refer to the size of the normal paragraph indentation rather than specify something specific (looking at the code for the documentclass) like 10pt or 2em, or whatever.

**Important** I do ***not*** want to indent the entire proof, including the first line that contains "Proof" — just that first line.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep % WHAT GOES IN PLACE OF \labelsep??
        \itshape
    #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Lots of text here.

\begin{thm}
This is true.
\end{thm}

\begin{proof}
It's ovvious!
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

On the output I've indicated graphically what I want to move.

[image: How indent just 1st line of proof as indicated?]

Comment: `\hskip\dimexpr\labelsep+\parindent\relax`

Comment: Just replace [\proofname] with [\indent\proofname].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a new length that's set to `\parindent` at begin document, so it will be available inside lists (that may reset `\parindent`).

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\normalparindent}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\normalparindent}{\parindent}}
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep\hskip\normalparindent
        \itshape
    #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Lots of text here.

\begin{thm}
This is true.
\end{thm}

\begin{proof}
It's obvious!
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A more compact version using `xpatch`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{amsthm,xpatch}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\newlength{\normalparindent}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\normalparindent}{\parindent}}
\xpatchcmd{\proof}{\hskip\labelsep}{\hskip\labelsep\hskip\normalparindent}{}{}

\begin{document}

Lots of text here.

\begin{thm}
This is true.
\end{thm}

\begin{proof}
It's obvious!
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why does you "compact version", at least, not work if I also use `amsthm` to define theorem styles? See added example in my OP, please.

Comment: I meant `thmtools`, not `amsthm`. I've found that I merely need to move the `\xpatchcommand` expression to go before loading `thmtools`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd imagine you can just set the proof as a regular paragraph, not as part of a list.

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\newlength{\storeparindent}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\storeparindent}{\parindent}}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \vspace{6\p@\@plus6\p@}%
  {\itshape #1\@addpunct{.}}\hspace*{\labelsep}%
  \ignorespaces
}{%
  \popQED
  \@endpefalse
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Lots of text here.

\begin{thm}
This is true.
\end{thm}

\begin{proof}
It's obvious!
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

This will ensure that the "`proof` paragraph" will indent the same way other paragraphs should. Also, if the document class resets `\parindent`, the `proof` environment will follow suit.

You may wish to play a little with the post-`proof` spacing, since lists do have that.